# stretch cell using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

Good Day

 i have this issue

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<td>a</td><td>a</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>a</td><td>a</td></tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">b</td>

</tr>
<tr><td class="test">c</td></tr>


</table>
```

You can see here http://jsfiddle.net/GfQyg/

What i want to do is :
use css in class "test" to add colspan to the last row so it fits the table
is it possible ?

### i dont want to modify the html

i need only to modify the css
Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't you use colspan? It's valid?

Comment: Just for my curiosity, why do you want to do the colspan by css provided that td is already giving you that option? I really cannot imagine your purpose for doing that. 

EDIT: Agreed with @Aquillo

You can check the fiddle with td as colspan and the obvious output that you can get. http://jsfiddle.net/GfQyg/1/

Comment: If you can't change html then use javascript to add the colspan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following script to do this: change class="test" to id="test" &

```
<script>
function displayResult()
{
 document.getElementById("test").colSpan="2";
}
 </script>
```

and call displayResult as :

```
<body onload="displayResult()" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CSS3 column-span` [column-span link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-span.asp)

But I suggested to use `colspan`.

Comment: are you sure? As I saw your link with NO FIREFOX COMPATIBILITY as well as not an ideal colspan solution for tables. Can you do a Fiddle and send me your research link? I will be curious to know how do you do it taking the same question as posted by user1000744. - @newbie

Comment: I provided a link and you can test it there.

Comment: i have done all my changes based on row background, but in chrome, this background was repeating in each cell, so i moved to cell background, but now i have to stretch each cell to colspan2